# How to use list comprehension in pandas to create a new series for a plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This is by far the most difficult problem I have faced. I am trying to create plots indexed on ratetype. For example, a matrix of unique ratetype x avg customer number for that ratetype is what I want to create efficiently. The lambda expression for getting the rows where the value is equal to each individual ratetype then getting the average customer number for that type then creating a series based on these two lists that are equal in size and length and accurate, is way over my head for pandas.

The number of different ratetypes can be in the hundreds. Reading it into a list via lambda would logically be a better choice than hard coding each possibility, as the list is going to only increase in size and new variability.

```
""" a section of the data for example use. Working with column "Ratetype"   
column "NumberofCustomers" to work towards getting something like 
list1 = unique occurs of ratetypes
list2 = avg number of customers for each ratetype
rt =['fixed','variable',..]
avg_cust_numbers = [45.3,23.1,...]

**basically for each ratetype: get mean of all row data for custno column**

ratetype,numberofcustomers   
fixed,1232
variable, 1100
vec, 199    
ind, 1211    
alg, 123    
bfd, 788    
csv, 129    
ggg, 1100    
aaa, 566    
acc, 439
"""
df['ratetype','number_of_customers']
fixed = df.loc['ratetype']=='fixed']
avg_fixed_custno = fixed.mean()

rt_counts = df.ratetype.value_counts()
rt_uniques = df.ratetype.unique()
# rt_uniques would be same size vector as avg_cust_nos, has to be anyway
avg_cust_nos = [avg_fixed_custno, avg_variable_custno]
```

My goal is to create and plot these subplots using matplot.pyplot.

```
 data = {'ratetypes': pd.Series(rt_counts, index=rt_uniques),
'Avg_cust_numbers': pd.Series(avg_cust_nos, index=rt_uniques),
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by=['ratetypes'], ascending=False)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):
   df[c].plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[i], figsize=(12, 10), title=c)
   plt.savefig('custno_byrate.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Could you provide a small subset of your data to create a workable example?

Comment: If you abstract your problem a bit that may surely help you write a more understandable question, i.e. working with "A", "B", "C" as column names, using small example datasets that you can hardcode in the code and finally clearly stating the problem in terms of those numbers used.

Comment: how's that now?